# Windows Phone - get user selected Cellular system settings

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, application-settings, appsettings, cellular-network

I would need to check if user in phone settings selected option 4G or 3G.

For example if user system settings are 4G but

```
InternetConnectionProfile.WwanConnectionProfileDetails.GetCurrentDataClass();
```

Would return different value then 4G I could redirect him to phone settings (ms-settings-cellular://) so that he can disable 4G.

However currently i can't find way to check current user system settings.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in one of my apps:

```
private const int IANA_INTERFACE_TYPE_WIFI = 71;
private static bool getCurrentConnection()
{
        ConnectionProfile internetConnectionProfile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

        // Check the connection details.
        if (internetConnectionProfile.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType != IANA_INTERFACE_TYPE_WIFI)
        {
            // Connection is not a Wi-Fi connection. 
            return false;
            //if (internetConnectionProfile.GetConnectionCost().Roaming)
            //{
            //    // User is roaming. Don't send data out.

            //}

            //if (internetConnectionProfile.GetConnectionCost().ApproachingDataLimit)
            //{
            //    // User is approaching data limit. Send low-resolution images.

            //}

            //if (internetConnectionProfile.GetConnectionCost().OverDataLimit)
            //{
            //    // User is over data limit. Don't send data out.

            //}
        }
        else
        {
            //Connection is a Wi-Fi connection. Data restrictions are not necessary.                        
            return true;
        }

}
```

You can also try this: [How can I check for 3G, wifi, EDGE, Cellular Networks in Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325627/how-can-i-check-for-3g-wifi-edge-cellular-networks-in-windows-phone-7)